# Tutorial doesn't work to create my first Ubuntu Mobile application

Tags: qt

I followed the guide to create my first Ubuntu Mobile application "currency converter" with QTCreator and QT5. However, the compiler returned the following error message:

```
module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed 
     import QtQuick 2.0
```

The fact is, if I run qmlscene from the terminal, it works fine.
QT5 is absolutely installed.

There must be something I should configure in QTCreator that I am not aware of.

Comment: I think there is some information missing here.  Are you trying to build and run in QtCreator?  Has QtCreator been configured to use Qt5 instead of Qt4.x? You might also find that you get better responses on the sister site, StackOverflow.com .

Comment: This belongs on SO as jwernerny commented. Please don't re-ask it there as this can get migrated.